# MongoDB query to return a count of entries under three different groups

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a mongoDB query that will return the total number of elements in three different groups. The database is concerning passengers of the titanic with the task of returning the total number of people under the age of 18 that did not survive categorised by which class they were in. The output I am after should look something like this:

```
{"_id" : {"Class" : 3, "Survived" : "No", "Total" : 18}}
{"_id" : {"Class" : 2, "Survived" : "No", "Total" : 23}}
{"_id" : {"Class" : 1, "Survived" : "No", "Total" : 12}}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
db.passangers.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"Age": {$lt: 18},"Survived": "No"}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {Class: "$Pclass", Survived: "$Survived"}}
  },
  { $count: "Survived"},
  {
    "$sort": {"Pclass": -1}
  }
])
```

but it only seems to output:

```
{"Survived" : 17}
```

Sorry if I did not provide enough information but I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. The problem with your query is that you are creating the groups without counting the number of elements in each group. So, when you count them later, it returns 17, which is the number of different values in `Pclass`. Is the following query what you are looking for:

```
db.passangers.aggregate([   
  {  
    "$match": {"Age": {$lt: 18},"Survived": "No"} 
  },
  {    
    "$group": { 
      _id: {Class: "$Pclass", Survived: "$Survived"},  Total: {$sum:1}}
  },
  { 
    "$sort": {"Pclass": -1}
  }
])
```

You will obtain:

```
{ "_id" : { "Class" : 3, "Survived" : "No" }, "Total" : 18 }
{ "_id" : { "Class" : 2, "Survived" : "No" }, "Total" : 23 }
{ "_id" : { "Class" : 1, "Survived" : "No" }, "Total" : 12 }
```

Comment: That works perfectly and I now understand my mistake. Cheers for the help!